# Why does pdf.js stop converting when changing the browser tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf.js

I am using the code in http://jsfiddle.net/LUNaJ/126/ to convert pdf pages to `canvas`. It works fine. However, when it starts converting (i.e. the progress bar is changing) then I go to another tab (in chrome) the code stops converting till I return the same tab. Why does this happen and can it be fixed?

Comment: Are you using setTimeout/setInterval to process the PDF?

Comment: @Psyco430404 No, I am not.

Comment: PDF.js is using setTimeout and requestAnimation frame when painting to be responsive as UI (and save CPU power).